# How to sum STD_LOGIC_VECTOR in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, addition

I'm trying to sum the sample values of 8 ADC's. Divide them by 8 and return the result via a DAC. I've made a case statement that provides the user to choose between summing the whole or just outputting one channel.
The problem that I encounter is that the result is "flickering". It often does what it must do, but sometimes it gives what it seems higher values.
Also the individual channels seem much much worse than the summed value. I got the feeling it synthesizes two different things for summing and individual channels or something.
I think it might have something do with how I sum the vectors, but I'm not experienced enough to tell if what I'm doing is wrong or not.
Does anybody perhaps know what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

```js
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY sum IS
PORT(
 CLK_IN    : IN  STD_LOGIC; -- 200MHz
 RESET    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
 SUM_EN    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
 SUM_VALID   :  IN  STD_LOGIC;
 
 CHANNEL_IN_1  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_2  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_3  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_4  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_5  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_6  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_7  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 CHANNEL_IN_8  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
  
 MODE_DATA   : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);

 DATA_OUT   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := x"80";
 SUM_READY   : OUT STD_LOGIC := '0');
END sum;

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF sum IS

-- input output registers
 SIGNAL r_sum_en   :  STD_LOGIC := '0';
 SIGNAL r_sum_en_edge :  STD_LOGIC := '0';
 SIGNAL r_sum_valid  :  STD_LOGIC := '0';
 SIGNAL r_sum_ready  :  STD_LOGIC := '0';
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_1  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_2  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_3  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_4  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_5  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_6  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_7  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_channel_in_8  :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_mode_data   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 3 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');
 SIGNAL r_data_out   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 ) := x"80";

-- logic signals
 TYPE machine IS (idle, initialise, summing, waiting, averaging, delivering);
 SIGNAL state : machine;

BEGIN
 r_channel_in_1  <= CHANNEL_IN_1 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_2  <= CHANNEL_IN_2 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_3  <= CHANNEL_IN_3 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_4  <= CHANNEL_IN_4 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_5  <= CHANNEL_IN_5 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_6  <= CHANNEL_IN_6 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_7  <= CHANNEL_IN_7 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_channel_in_8  <= CHANNEL_IN_8 WHEN r_sum_en = '1' ELSE x"80";
 r_sum_en  <= SUM_EN;
 r_mode_data  <= MODE_DATA;
 r_sum_valid  <= SUM_VALID;
 DATA_OUT   <= r_data_out;
 SUM_READY   <= r_sum_ready;

 PROCESS (CLK_IN, RESET) IS
  VARIABLE average : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_5 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_7 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
  VARIABLE hold_channel_8 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
 BEGIN
  IF RESET = '1' THEN
   r_sum_ready  <= '0';
   r_data_out   <= x"80";
   hold_channel_1 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_2 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_3 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_4 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_5 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_6 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_7 := (others => '0');
   hold_channel_8 := (others => '0');

  ELSIF rising_edge(CLK_IN) THEN
   CASE state IS
    WHEN idle =>
     r_sum_en_edge <= r_sum_en;
     IF r_sum_en = '1' AND r_sum_en_edge = '0' THEN
      state <= initialise;
     ELSE state <= idle; END IF;
     r_sum_ready <= '0';
     r_sum_ready  <= '0';
     r_data_out   <= x"80";
     hold_channel_1 := x"080";
     hold_channel_2 := x"080";
     hold_channel_3 := x"080";
     hold_channel_4 := x"080";
     hold_channel_5 := x"080";
     hold_channel_6 := x"080";
     hold_channel_7 := x"080";
     hold_channel_8 := x"080";
    WHEN initialise =>

     IF r_sum_valid = '1' THEN
      state <= summing;
      hold_channel_1(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_1;
      hold_channel_2(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_2;
      hold_channel_3(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_3;
      hold_channel_4(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_4;
      hold_channel_5(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_5;
      hold_channel_6(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_6;
      hold_channel_7(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_7;
      hold_channel_8(7 DOWNTO 0) := r_channel_in_8;
     ELSE
      state <= initialise;
     END IF;
     r_sum_ready <= '0';
    WHEN summing =>
     CASE r_mode_data IS
      WHEN x"0" => average := hold_channel_1 + hold_channel_2 + hold_channel_3 + hold_channel_4 + hold_channel_5 + hold_channel_6 + hold_channel_7 + hold_channel_8 ;
      WHEN x"1" => average := hold_channel_1;
      WHEN x"2" => average := hold_channel_2;
      WHEN x"3" => average := hold_channel_3;
      WHEN x"4" => average := hold_channel_4;
      WHEN x"5" => average := hold_channel_5;
      WHEN x"6" => average := hold_channel_6;
      WHEN x"7" => average := hold_channel_7;
      WHEN x"8" => average := hold_channel_8;
      WHEN others => null;
     END CASE;
     state <= waiting;
     r_sum_ready <= '0';
    WHEN waiting =>
     state <= averaging;
     r_sum_ready <= '0';
    WHEN averaging =>
     CASE r_mode_data IS
      WHEN x"0" => r_data_out <= average (10 DOWNTO 3);
      WHEN others => r_data_out <= average (7 DOWNTO 0);
     END CASE;
     r_sum_ready <= '0';
     state <= delivering;
    WHEN delivering =>
     r_sum_ready <= '1';
     IF r_sum_en = '1' THEN
      state <= initialise;
     ELSE state <= idle; END IF;
    WHEN others =>
     state <= idle;
   END CASE;

  END IF;

 END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Comment: Can you provide a simulation showing the bad behavior?

Comment: The problem is unfortunately not shown in simulations. Only when it's downloaded to the FPGA. I've got this alot, in simulations it all works perfectly but in real life it doesn't work....

Comment: If circuit behavior is different from simulated the problem is either simulation stimuli or the problem lies elsewhere. Warnings from synthesis? Interface timing?  Noise on inputs controlling state machine branching or operation? Power? Ground loops? Your average calculation and best sum seems correct. You're asking readers to peer through a keyhole with a restricted field of view while telling them it's not a digital problem showing up in simulation without demonstrating that. Is this [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here?

Comment: I get some understandable warnings from other parts, but not on this one. The main question was if the summing would work this way. Since I've no idea how long this operation would take, I thought maybe it would've been a timing issue. Is there a way to analyse this?

Comment: I suspect that your flickering problem is due to the lack of synchronization between your ADC and your design: when your `CLK_IN` rising edge occurs exactly at the same time as a change of the input data, your `hold_channel_x` registers sample anything (some bits of the previous value, some of the new one, some metastable....) If I am right, you need a way to synchronize your design with the ADCs. Note: your design is far more complicated than needed. VHDL is a **high** level language (array types, loops...).

Comment: Have you run the "Timing Analysis" to meet your clocks requirements?

Comment: It was indeed the synch with the ADCs. I rewrote the driver and now it's working perfectly! What do you mean by far more complicated than need Renaud? I've learned that you shouldn't alter ports in the architecture, but use registers instead.

Comment: @Xinq You could, for instance, declare a subtype for your data, an array type of it and replace your `r_channel_in_x` signals and `hold_channel_x` variables by one single array signal and one single array variable. Then, you could use for loops and aggregate notation to handle them. This would avoid copying 8 times the (almost) same statements.

Comment: Ah yeah. I've tried that before, but it didn't quite go as planned unfortunately. But thanks for the tip, I'll start experimenting with it!